# How to share GPS data as part of an AR app

Tags: android, server, gps, android-augmented-reality

I would like to build an app that uses GPS coordinates and then Augments the phone's camera with a straight line to a friends' GPS location and modifies the line graphics accordingly in real-time based on the users' movements.

I'm confused about what to use in order to create it- I've googled for buzz words like Unity, ARkit and python for Android....but I can't really understand what to use and how?

If I do need a server- what service should I use? this one?https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/?pli=1

and on which platform should I write the app? Unity?

I've seen answers like: [Real time sharing of GPS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900401/real-time-sharing-of-gps-location) but all these answers were received quite a long time ago.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unity is the easiest to get started with. You likely won't even need to make use of any AR engines outside of just accessing the camera. You'll just need to know which direction the phone is facing.

You'll need a database to store a user ID and GPS location at minimum.

GPS can be accessed in Unity using Input.location.

Keep in mind that GPS is currently accurate to ~5-10 metres, so at close range your line may be a little off the other device.

Comment: great contribution, can you please add your thoughts about the recommended server service? I have 0 knowledge at servers..